# Magento 2 - Enabled show/hide functionality on header search

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, search

I've currently got the following phtml file in my theme:

> Vender/Theme/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml

and the following js file inside of my theme as well:

> Vender/Theme/Magento_Search/web/form-mini.js

I've done some changes to the **form-mini.js** trying to show and hide the search on a desktop site as well as the mobile side.

```
mediaCheck({
    //media: '(max-width: 768px)',
     entry: function () {
         this.isExpandable = true;
     }.bind(this),
         exit: function () {
         this.isExpandable = false;
         this.element.removeAttr('aria-expanded');
    }.bind(this)
});
```

So i commented out the media query to stop the script running on anything less than **768px** but, nothing. On clicking the label the ***aria-expanded*** still doesn't toggle.

This is my first time looking at the search functionality, any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: this is my website url http://202.149.209.212:9090/ktas/ please help me how i can make serach show hide on desktop.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123400)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the `media` parameter to the `mediaCheck` function:

```
mediaCheck({
    media: 'all',
    entry: function () {
        this.isExpandable = true;
    }.bind(this),
    exit: function () {
        this.isExpandable = false;
        this.element.removeAttr('aria-expanded');
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Setting it to `all` means that it will never switch to the desktop settings.

There are some CSS changes that need to be made it get the basic show/hide functionality. Copy **vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_CatalogSearch/web/css/source/_module.less** to your theme in **{theme}/Magento_CatalogSearch/web/css/source/_module.less**.

At line 211, we should remove this code:

```
.label {
    &:extend(.abs-visually-hidden-desktop all);
}
```

This will make the label element visible in desktop.

At line 227, remove this:

```
input {
    .lib-input-placeholder(@form-element-input-placeholder__color);
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 35px;
    position: static;
}
```

now the input element will be hidden and will show when the label element is clicked in both mobile and desktop.

There are other CSS tweaks that you'll need to make to get it to look good, for example the rule that hides the input is at line 68 and does so by setting `left: -300%;`, however in desktop the input is still visible if the window is wide enough.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't need the less portion as i'm using sass to overwrite the blank theme, but the media query 'all' worked a treat. Can't tell you how much i was pulling out my hair trying to figure this out. Will award bounty in... 7 hours >_< haha

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @Aaron Allen, Please help to solve the problem related to this topic. [Magento 2 Сlicking on the search box does not work on iPad, when I set the width: 0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184600/magento-2-%D0%A1licking-on-the-search-box-does-not-work-on-ipad-when-i-set-the-width)